# paper print design on photoshop

Tags: logo, print-design, paper

I am looking for some tutorial for this kind of graphic design -

I don't know what to call this, but the logo is looking like it is printed on paper

[image]

does anyone know how this is done ?

Comment: I suspect it's merely printed on stock, then photographed. It's not a "manipulation" or "creation" other than the logo itself. It's a photograph.

Comment: I think they just used the distort tool to give the image some perspective on top of a photo of paper. FYI, that's not emulating printed ink (intentionally or not). If anything, it's emulating foil embossing.

Comment: I was thinking spot UV on wove paper, but the drop shadow does look a little too deep. I'm not saying it was Aliens but...

Answer (score 3):

This looks very much like it was made from one of the Photoshop mockup templates that have become so abundant on the web since Smart Objects (CS4) arrived on the scene. They make it easy for beginners (and quick for designers) to create sophisticated, highly realistic mockups of designs in context. Even [deep debossing and fabric textures](http://www.pixeden.com/psd-mock-up-templates/linen-logo-mock-up-template) are out there in "instant mockup" form.

[image: Linen texture PSD mockup]

[Thermographic printing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermographic_printing) does give a raised, shiny effect similar to your example, but it usually doesn't achieve that degree of smoothness. Here's a good example of what it typically looks like close up.

[image: Example of thermographic raised print]

A very high-quality wax or laser printer might also produce a similar effect, seen in extreme close-up, since both techniques create a slightly raised image that sits on top of the substrate.

If you're looking to create something in real life that gives this effect, thermography (if you don't mind the slightly bubbly texture) or spot UV coating are probably your best bets.

Comment: You'll notice the original link has some of the same thermo-texture, but it is very localized, like it was a tight gradient overlay with a "stained glass" effect applied to it and then overlayed.

Comment: Yes, I did notice that. It would be easier to distinguish if the image were larger. As it is, the effect is so subtle I'm still unsure if it's reals or just an image-processing artifact.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's some kind of embossed, varnished and/or treated printing. There's some examples here that mimic that sort of printed effect: http://designinstruct.com/print-design/a-guide-to-popular-printing-techniques/

There's also a couple of tutorials that can teach you how to mimic these effects digitally, such as this one: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/letterpress-embosed-text-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is physically printed at all for some practical reasons.

- There are some slight inconsistencies
- The placement on a paper is - to put it mildly - odd.
- If it is printed, I doubt this would be something that you could
  stick in a normal printer.
- In addition it does not look like campusdiversity.com exists at all.

So, in conclusion, it is mimicking that velvety-print method. I believe it is called flocking. Here is a real-life example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a printed effect. I have a physical sample of my company logo printed on a book cover using this same effect to the degree that it is raised almost 1.5mm above the surface.

photoslive.com are able to do the same - but i have not been able to determine what equipment is used.